# Sorting bash arguments alphabetically

Tags: bash

How can I take sort bash arguments alphabetically?

```
$ ./script.sh bbb aaa ddd ccc
```

and put it into an array such that I now have an array {aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd}

Comment: you already have them in `$@`

Comment: Yes, but they aren't sorted.

Comment: yep its not, please check my Answer just to do tht :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
A=( $(sort <(printf "%s\n" "$@")) )

printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}"
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

It is using steps:

1. sort the `arguments list i.e.`"$@"`
2. store output of sort in an array
3. Print the sorted array

Comment: I don't understand the goal of 1st step: Why not simply `declare -a A=($(sort <(printf "%s\n" "$@")))` ?

Comment: Sure that step can be eliminated, that is just for demonstration purpose. May I add that core of the answer is in 2nd step not 1st.

Comment: Users should be aware that this doesn't work with whitespace or special characters.

Comment: @rici It splits up the result based on IFS, which includes spaces by default.

Comment: @thatotherguy: `sortargs() { mapfile -t $1 < <(printf "%s\n" "${@:2}"|sort); }; sortargs A "foo bar" "*" "" $'baz\tcow'; printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}"`. Still fails on newlines, of course.

Answer (score 4):

I hope following 2 lines will help.

```
sorted=$(printf '%s\n' "$@"|sort)

echo $sorted
```

This will give you a sorted cmdline args.I wonder though why its needed :)

**But anyway it will sort your cmdlines**

Removed whatever was not required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an invocation that breaks all the other solutions proposed here:

```
./script.sh "foo bar" "*" "" $'baz\ncow'
```

Here's a piece of code that works correctly:

```
array=()
(( $# )) && while IFS= read -r -d '' var
do
  array+=("$var")
done <  <(printf "%s\0" "$@" | sort -z)
```

Comment: I downvoted this because I don't know a lot of case where sorting long field with linebreak are really a need. In the other hand, I know a lot of cases where quick sort on small fields may be usefull.

Comment: @F.Hauri It was a poorly written question with no mention of edge cases. I would have down voted the question.

Comment: @F.Hauri As long as you're doing it for fair and logical reasons and not petty childishness, I'm fine with that.

Comment: @jaypal I agreee, and I won't downvote this answer at all because there is a real effort to present a reliable way of working with *null terminated strings*, but SO won't let me correct my vote now...