# Sorting an array of pathnames (strings) [Bash]

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, sorting

I have seen way too many duplicates of this, but none of the answer codes or tips ever helped me, so I'm left confused.

```
input=/foo/bar/*;
#Contains something along the lines of 
#/foo/bar/file1 /foo/bar/file2 /foo/bar/file3
#And I simply need
#/foo/bar/file3 /foo/bar/file2 /foo/bar/file1

output=($(for l in ${input[@]}; do echo $l; done | sort));
#Doesn't work, returns only the last entry from input

output=$(sort -nr ${input});
#Works, returns everything correctly reversed, but outputs the file contents and not the pathnames;
output=($(sort -nr ${input}));
#Outputs only the last entry and also its contents and not the pathname;
```

I tried many more options, but I'm not gonna fill this whole page with them, you get the gist.

*Duplicates:* (None of them helpful to me)

[How can I sort the string array in linux bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881346/how-can-i-sort-the-string-array-in-linux-bash-shell)

[How to sort an array in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash)

[custom sort bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813253/custom-sort-bash-array)

[Sorting bash arguments alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574185/sorting-bash-arguments-alphabetically)

Comment: `$input` is not an array, it's a string. Also, how is `${a[@]}` populated?

Comment: @choroba Ops, I just copy and pasted from the other SO question because I didn't have the code anymore.

Comment: `input` contains exactly the string `/foo/bar/*`; pathname expansion does not occur in assignment statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort -r` with `printf`, where `input` containg glob string to match your filenames:

```
sort -r <(printf "%s\n" $input)
```

Comment: Agreed, really clever, compact and intuitive. Thank you!

Comment: Beware, though: it also doesn't work if the value of `input` contains any whitespace.

Comment: Yes I know about files with spaces but as per OP has filenames as `/foo/bar/file1 /foo/bar/file2 /foo/bar/file3`. Besides I've tested this with filenames with spaces as well. I think filenames with newlines will have issues though.

Comment: Yeah, I have no intention of using spaces in my pathnames, it's a static directory with set (by me) filenames - I just wanted for it to be a little modular.

Answer (score 3):

You're confused about what is an array in bash: this does not declare an array:

```
input=/foo/bar/*
```

`$input` is just the string `"/foo/bar/*"` -- the list of files does not get expanded until you do something like `for i in ${input[@]}` where the "array" expansion is unquoted.

You want this:

```
input=( /foo/bar/* )
mapfile -t output < <(printf "%s\n" "${input[@]}" | sort -nr)
```

I don't have time to explain it. I'll come back later.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it. I'm pretty new to Bash, and considering nearly every list-type structure in C++, Lua, Python... (VB.NET - but I don't want to talk about that) is an array I automatically assumed the same here.

Comment: `bash` is very poor in data structures, because it wasn't designed to process data; it's a glue language to facilitate running other programs.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
input=`foo/bar/*`
output=`for l in $input ; do echo $l ; done | sort -r`
```